# Summation using pandas.eval brings NaN messages for columns not included in both dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, eval

I'm trying to make a cumulative dataframe from various fragmented small dataframes.

For example, I have fragmented small dataframe A and B such as:

```
      a  c
100   1  2
200   5  6

      a  b  d
100   2  3  8
200   9  1  9

A = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2],[5,6]], index=[100,200], columns=['a','c'])

B = pd.DataFrame(data = [[2,3,8],[9,1,9]], index=[100,200], columns=['a','b','d'])
```

and I want to add these into a cumulative dataframe c

```
      a  b  c  d
100   0  0  0  0
200   0  0  0  0

C = pd.DataFrame(data = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]], index=[100,200], columns=['a','b','c','d'])
```

So what I want to do is, add A and B to C to make:

```
      a   b  c  d
100   3   3  2  8
200   14  1  6  9
```

what I did first was something like:

```
C[A.columns] += A
C[B.columns] += B
```

Which works fine, and brings the desired output.

However, in my real application, efficiency issues rise since the size of A, B, and C is quite big, and there are many, many fragmented dataframes like A and B

Therefore, I have looked for some alternative methods, and I found pandas.eval pretty powerful in big-sized matrix operations.

What I tried is:

```
import pandas as pd
C = pd.eval('C+A')
C = pd.eval('C+B')
```

However, In this case, columns not included in A or B becomes NaN...

```
out: 
       a   b    c   d
100  1.0 NaN  2.0 NaN
200  5.0 NaN  6.0 NaN

out:
        a   b   c   d
100   3.0 NaN NaN NaN
200  14.0 NaN NaN NaN
```

Any suggestions to make the desired operation more efficiently? Any suggestions would be appreciated (I don't necessarily have to use pd.eval)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sometime using `pd.eval` is tricky.

Here you need to use the columns that are being added in the C df and we need to pass the list of columns using a variable when using pd.eval.

```
a_cols = A.columns
b_cols = B.columns
C[a_cols] = pd.eval('C[a_cols]+A', engine='python')
C[b_cols] = pd.eval('C[b_cols]+B', engine='python')

out:
      a  b  c  d
100   3  3  2  8
200  14  1  6  9
```

And for the engine we need to use `'python'` instead of `'numexpr'` which is default for engine.